# iOS URL Encode NSString and the result is always (null)

Tags: ios, nsstring, urlencode, nsurl

when I use NSASCIIStringEncoding to encode some Chinese character for a GET request.

```
NSLog(@"%@",searchText);
NSString *stringForSearch = [searchText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",stringForSearch);
```

2012-05-05 23:51:02.669 StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem[756:f803] 中

2012-05-05 23:51:06.305 StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem[756:f803] (null)

And first log is a Chinese character but the second log is always (null),
Pls help me with this , thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` insted of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`.